# Google Maps Marker click event that pulls a line from txt file in Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, kotlin

I am currently working on an Android project using Google Maps. I have functionality that allows them to click a marker when they are nearby and it will remove that marker and move it somewhere else nearby. However, I also want them to "collect" something when the marker is clicked. That something is a random line from a txt file that I have stored in my assets folder, but I can't figure out:

1) How to parse that file in the first place

2) How to grab a random line from that file and store it somewhere else when the marker is clicked

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you another way to do so. 
You have a marker, add some information to it. For example, a snippet. And after marker is clicked you store that.

If you want get some info from assets you should initilize random array onMapReady() and do some staff with it.